# Looking for API optimization suggestions

Tags: php, mysql, api, memcached, redis

In the past I had asked a few questions about how to create my own API to allow external sites access to my db I store in the database. This particular question is I'm asking for suggestions on how to optimize the API access for external sites to help keep the local server load down. First the way the API is setup is it uses MySQL that holds the data and php to serve the data. The API itself is called by a URL with an API key in the URL. For example:

```
http://mysite.com/get_listings.php?key=somekey
```

Then my script does what it needs to do for the action above and then return the results in json format. Currently the API is serving 10-15k unique calls a month and I am adding another group of sites that will bring in another 20-30k unique calls a month on top of what the API is serving now. There is no caching going on, its just a straight call to my API via the php script and it queries the MySQL database every call. The type of data that it returns is basically stories and profile information and the calls are things like latest stories, profile of the story author and story details.

Besides the normal optimization of php code and optimizing MySQL queries and indexes can you suggest any other optimization techniques that can help keep the server load down and still serve the API to the external sites fast? I understand the external sites themselves should be doing some sort of caching on their end as well. But on my end do you suggest caching the results from the db then serving the cache? If so would using memcache be a good choice? Or perhaps storing the json results in redis? Or perhaps a simple file caching system would work? Anything other than caching? Obviously server hardware can make a difference but out of the scope of this post. I will say though that I will be getting a whole new server that will only be dedicated to doing this.

I do have root access to install additional software, if that helps.

Comment: 50k per month it's nothing. Don't worry about it.

Comment: @OZ_ Actually if this other place signs on it could jump to over a million. The main purpose is trying to find a solution that will work well now but also can scale to handle more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have the capacity to scale mysql with additional read-only nodes, you should really start using Redis or Memcached. Redis might be better at handling complex data-types. Here is a recipe.

1. https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis - install this, it will help you to interface with Redis seamlessly from PHP.
2. Classify your requests by certain keys. For example get_listings.php?key=somekey would probably use $redis->hget('listings',$somekey);
3. Store results serialised or in JSON.
4. When database is updated, be sure to destroy or update relevant indexes in Redis. If you are using back-end with MVC, then model behaviour handlers could do that for you. For example when new comment is posted, update Redis sorted list.
5. You can mix and match different structures. For example fetch the key from sorted list, then pull the actual data from the hash.

If you are using redis for permanent storage, make sure that your PHP knows how to clean it up. In my experience it turned out to be quite resilient, although I still store data in MySQL .

Redis is great if you understand [computation complexities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory).

Comment: Thanks for the info! Question, is there any chances of "clashes" when sites access the api and my code is in the process of updating a redis entry with new data? Also do you recommend authorizing an api access using mysql or store that info in redis?

Comment: Redis is using blocking and even allows transactions. I would suggest to eliminate MySQL completely from your most-requested APIs then it won't be a bottle-neck. Even if you hold cache for a minute it's amazing much more efficient Redis is.

Comment: Ok, is there any specific settings I should adjust to optimize redis further that you recommend? Or is it pretty good with the out of the box settings?

Comment: Default setting is OK. John, you can get in touch with me through links in my profile, we can chat further over emails. I'd be glad to help.